# compare folder content with mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, file

I want to check if there are any filenames in this folder which are not in the mysql database, but I cant seem to find a way to do this as the loop for fetching the mysql data has to be inside the loop for reading the directory (as far as I can figure),which messes the whole proccess up. Is there another way to do this:

```
if ($handle = opendir('video/test')) {

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
       if ($entry !== "." && $entry !== ".."){

  $delfile =  "SELECT * FROM files WHERE filename <> '$entry'";
  $delfile = $db->query($delfile);

  while($row = $delfile->fetch_assoc()){
         echo $row['filename'];

      }
    }
  }
   closedir($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [glob](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to get an array of filenames

```
$filenames = glob( 'video/test' );
```

then use MySQL's [in](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) to check the table

```
$sql = sprintf( 'select * from files where filename not in ("%s")', implode( '","', $filenames ) );
```

no loops!

Comment: that looks good. How do I incorporate the mysqli connect to this